# SQL: replace a block of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a big table containing all my financial transactions.  Then I do a fresh import from my accounting system and get updated entries for December 2017 and January 2018.  I would like to clear out all rows for those months the big table and replace them with the newly imported data.

I can do this with two statements; something like this:

```
DELETE bt
  FROM big_table AS bt
  JOIN new_data AS nd
 WHERE bt.year = nd.year
   AND bt.month = nd.month

INSERT INTO bt
SELECT *
  FROM new_data
```

**Is there an elegant way to do this in one statement?**  Or is this the recommended approach?  The MERGE statement seems to process one record at a time, rather than whole blocks of (year, month) combinations.

I'm interested particularly in standard SQL, PostgreSQL, MS SQL Server, but any advice is appreciated.

I'm also open to suggestions that leave `big_table` unchanged, and instead put all the data into a new table, if that helps the resulting query to be simpler or more elegant.

Comment: One thing you can do with some databases (e.g. SQL Server and Oracle) is to partition your table into chunks (in your example, by month, say.) Then you can `TRUNCATE` entire months virtually instantaneously (because it's a non-logged operation) while leaving the rest of the data in the table, and reload from fresh data. Here's a [SQL Server example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4436/sql-server-2016-truncate-table-with-partitions/). Typically, though, there's nothing much wrong with your initial approach, and nothing terribly elegant about trying to put it into one statement.

Comment: Well, your first query doesn't work in Postgres, unless you have a table called `bt`.  In that case, it would probably delete all rows.

Answer (score 1):

The MERGE statement can absolutely process a set of rows. In standard SQL this would be something like this:

```
merge into big_table bt
using (
  select *
  from new_table
) x on (x.month = bt.month and x.year = bt.year)
when matched then update
  set bt.col1 = x.col1, 
      bt.col2 = x.col2, 
      .... more columns ...
when not matched then insert (year, month, col1, col2, ...)
values (x.year, x.month, x.col1, x.col2, ... more columns);
```

Postgres however does not (yet) support the MERGE statement, but the `ON CONFLICT` clause of the `INSERT` statement can be used for that if you have a unique key constraint on `(month, year)`.

```
insert into big_table (year, month, col1, col2, ....)
select year, month, col1, col2, ... more columns ...
from new_data nd
on conflict (month, year) do update 
   set col1 = excluded.col1, 
       col2 = excluded.col2, 
       ... more columns ...;
```

Comment: Suppose the target table had data for January 2018, some of which was absent from the source table. I would like that data to be deleted from the target table. Would your query achieve this?

Comment: @Doradus: no it wouldn't.